# How can I find the library using play services as `10.2.0` version in my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play

In my app gradle I use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
```

But it says there is a dependency that uses `10.2.0` version. But I couldn't find that dependency.

I don't want to update to 10.2.0, don't advice this.

How can I find the library using play services as `10.2.0` version?

Comment: If you are using windows run gradlew app:dependencies in terminal of android studio

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing - 
This option will only work if you're using *Android studio with default settings on Windows OS*

- Press `Ctrl + Shift + F`
- Search `10.2.0`
  You'll have the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'

Replace these lines with below line 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
```